# Drop rows where column duplicate and and other column null

Tags: python, null, duplicates, mask, drop

Seeking to drop rows where `col1` is duplicate and `col2` is `null`, but only when both conditions are met.

Therefore, where `col1` is duplicate and `col2` is not `null`, row should not be dropped.

```
d = {'col1': ['A1', 'B4', 'A2', 'A1', 'B4', 'B4'], 'col2': [np.nan, 'ref4', np.nan, 'ref3', 'ref1', 'ref3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

  col1  col2
0   A1   NaN
1   B4  ref4
2   A2   NaN
3   A1  ref3
4   B4  ref1
5   B4  ref3
```

`index row 0` satisfies both conditions and would therefore be the only row dropped

Output:

```
  col1  col2
1   B4  ref4
2   A2   NaN
3   A1  ref3
4   B4  ref1
5   B4  ref3
```

I have tried the following code but it does not perform as needed.....

```
m1 = df['col2'].notna()
m2 = df['col1'].duplicated()

df = df[m1 & m2]

print(df)
```

Comment: Maybe: `df[df['col1'].duplicated(keep=False) ^ df['col2'].isna()]` ?

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Thank you.  By the way what is the significance of the symbol '^' ?

Comment: This is a XOR: True ^ False -> True ; True ^ True -> False

Comment: does it mean that both conditions must be met?

Answer (score 1):

Create another dataframe that drops rows that meet that condition. `df_2 = df[(~df['col'].duplicated())&(df['col2'].isnull())]`.

Answer (score 0):

@Jon_Clements' comment is nice, but there's a problem with it. Using only the XOR operator in this case will result in removing rows where ***col1*** is not duplicate and ***col2*** is not null ***at the same time***.

Here's an example of this

```
  col1  col2
0   A1  NaN
1   B4  ref4
2   A2  NaN
3   A1  ref3
4   B4  ref1
5   B4  ref3
6   B5  ref5
```

To solve this use the following snippet:

```
df[df['col1'].duplicated(keep=False) ^ df['col2'].isna() | ~df['col1'].duplicated(keep=False) & ~df['col2'].isna()]
```

Results:

```
  col1  col2
1   B4  ref4
2   A2  NaN
3   A1  ref3
4   B4  ref1
5   B4  ref3
6   B5  ref5
```